# Two questions are what I wanted to ask

Tags: grammatical-number

1. In sentences like "Two questions are what I wanted to ask", should I treat the subject, "Two questions", as singular or plural?

   It seems more natural to treat it as plural. But when I reverse the subjects I'll need to use the singular form instead : "What I wanted to ask **is** two questions" and this doesn't look very natural.
2. Does the same apply to chronological sentences like "5 months is/are what I have left to finish this project of mine"?

Comment: While correct, "I wanted to ask two questions" and "I have 5 months left"  are more common constructs (also you need to include "have" in the second one.)

Comment: Clauses are singular by default, and the verb agrees with the subject. QED. So you're right to follow what sounds right. If it sounds good, it ***is*** good.

Comment: @alkenrinnstet: I can't see why you think they're different. If I order three pints of beer in a pub, and the barman only brings me two, I'll say *"Three beers **is** what I asked for."* It's difficult to find a credible real-world context for OP's version (for most purposes, it just looks like something only a non-native speaker would say). But I suppose if you were at a meeting where the general principle was "each attendee may only ask one question", you might just about be able to say *"Two questions is what I wanted to ask - but in the circumstances, I'll ask **Why only one?**"*

Comment: Why are answers being provided as comments? I understood this was inappropriate.

Comment: "Each attendee may only ask one question" vs " ... may ask only one question", or " ... may ask one question only" ? I feel it is not the same meaning ?

Comment: @Mark Thorin: Each thread should address only one question.

Answer (score 1):

I feel "two questions" as a whole (an unity, not as separate parts).

I would say "Two beers and some chips *is* what I ordered".

or "One hundred soldiers and two canons *was* just what the captain had to defend the fort".

Comment: Not even a single archdeacon?