# Is this correct: "Our listeners are what make X"?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, agreement, what

I listen to a podcast that I like, but every episodes ends with

> Our listeners are what make [podcast name] possible.

which makes me cringe a little each time I hear it. Is it just me, or is the sentence wrong? And if so, what is the correct form - should both verbs be singular?
And is there a difference between UK and US usage? (The podcast is based in the USA).

I found a [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130381/), but it does not apply exactly (and the  [one it links to](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67553/) only discusses cases where the sentence stars with a time interval).

Thank you.

Comment: IMO, you are right. What makes our podcast possible? Our listeners. Our listeners is what makes our podcast possible.

Comment: "A group/collection of our listeners" is what makes our podcast possible.

Comment: I think the following questions are relevant; I'm currently reading the answers there: [Can “what” be plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198968), [Singular or plural verb after “what”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114123/singular-or-plural-verb-after-what) It seems clear that the singular ("makes") would be valid here; like you, I'm not sure about "make."

Comment: "Our listeners" is definitely plural and would always use "are".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Our listeners are what make our podcast possible" is grammatical. (But it took a little while for me to figure that out; thank you to everyone else who left comments and answers!) Like you, I felt uncomfortable with it after you brought it up, and I'll discuss the reasons for that below, but they are based on semantics rather than purely on the grammatical structure.

As a subject, "our listeners" triggers plural agreement on the corresponding verb in all varieties of English that I know of. In this sentence, that verb is "are." It isn't anything like a collective noun: collective nouns, such as "collection" or "group," are *singular* in form (morphology) but plural in meaning. But "listeners" is clearly *plural* in form, as it has the plural suffix *-s*. As you said, the answers to the question about ['Is it “5–6 weeks are a lot of time” or “5–6 weeks is a lot of time”?'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67553/is-it-5-6-weeks-are-a-lot-of-time-or-5-6-weeks-is-a-lot-of-time?lq=1) only say it is possible to use singular verbs with nominally-plural subjects that are "quantities or measurements" (usually "of time, money, distance, weight"). There is no measurement involved in the noun phrase "our listeners," so I don't think it's natural to use a singular verb with it.

So that's what I'd say about the first verb in the sentence. But the verb "make/makes" is part of a later, distinct relative clause whose subject is the word "what." So to figure out which to use between "make" and "makes," we need to determine whether "what" is singular or plural here.

This is a tricky question, since relative pronouns always have one form, but can take different types of agreement depending on the situation.
A relevant situation that I have just thought of is the transparency of the relative pronoun "who" to person agreement, discussed in the following post: ["You who is" OR "you who are"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/304258/you-who-is-or-you-who-are). I think that I would *not* use person agreement in sentences like "Our listeners are what make [podcast name] possible." Here's what I mean. To simplify matters, assume we're talking to a single person, "Sally." I would say

> Sally, you are what makes [podcast name] possible.

rather than

> Sally, you are what make [podcast name] possible.

In fact, a [Google Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you%20are%20what%20make%2C%20you%20are%20what%20makes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20are%20what%20makes%3B%2Cc0) turns up no examples of the structure "you are what make"; "you are what makes" *is* attested, although rarely, and only consistently after the 1980s.

On the other hand, as FumbleFingers has discussed, it is *true* that "these are what make" is more frequent in the Google corpus than "these are what makes," and also, ["they are what make" is more frequent than "they are what makes.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=they+are+what+makes%2Cthey+are+what+make&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthey%20are%20what%20makes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthey%20are%20what%20make%3B%2Cc0)"

[image]

My interpretation of this is that in constructions like this with "what," the verb after "what" does not have to agree with the subject of the preceding clause.

However, it evidently can inflect for plurality. It does seem this is an exception to the default situation where "what" triggers singular agreement on a following verb. The [English Forums explanation](https://www.englishforums.com/English/AllPluralSingular/xkgvr/post.htm) that FumbleFingers linked to in a comment 
gives examples where a plural verb can/must be used if the complement includes a plural noun phrase (such as "What they desperately want are clothes and shelter"), but the relevant clause in the sentence you're asking about ("what make/makes [podcast name] possible") doesn't have a plural noun phrase complement. FumbleFingers' [grammarphobia](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/06/subject-complement.html) link also doesn't seem to cover sentences of this exact type. But perhaps it could simply be considered the inversion of "What make [podcast name] possible are our viewers," which is a sentence whose form is discussed (and confirmed to be grammatical) in the grammarphobia article. However, it doesn't seem safe to assume that we can invert the sentence and leave the verb the same.

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114123/singular-or-plural-verb-after-what) seems to indicate that if a relative pronoun such as "what" starts a "free relative clause," the word "what" does not have to agree in plurality with the preceding noun "listeners." From what I can tell, it is a [free relative clause](https://books.google.com/books?id=wWm8EbQwCZAC&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=bound%20relative%20clause%20definition&source=bl&ots=vvdGE4YZ96&sig=ZNFcxTEl7fhrO9d8GuUG7B-HJ-M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNq-i4lbbKAhUE52MKHTknDwcQ6AEIKzAF#v=onepage&q&f=false) in your sentence (I'm not even sure if bound relative clauses with "what" are possible in standard English; they usually use other relative pronouns such as "which" or "who"). This would mean that it's grammatically possible to treat "what" as either singular or plural; it appears that speakers usually do treat "what" as plural in this grammatical context (judging from the NGram that [Fumblefingers](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/300865/77227) has provided).

However, even if a plural verb is more commonly chosen, it does seem to be  possible for "what" to be taken as singular here and get singular verb agreement. FumbleFinger's ngram link indicates that a notable minority of speakers take this option in the Google Books corpus, and I think the evident opacity of the structure in modern usage to *personal* agreement (as shown in sentences using the pronoun "you") provides some analogical support to the idea that it can be opaque to *number* agreement as well. When I first read your post, my reaction was that I would say "Our listeners are what makes our podcast possible."

Here are some other example sentences where I would use a singular verb rather than agreeing with the plural subject of the main clause:

- They are what is wrong with this place.
- They are all that makes my life worth living.

Different speakers may have different intuitions about this, however.

Maybe a good way to think of it is this: just as you could say "our viewers are the thing that makes our podcast great," you could also say "our viewers are the things that make our podcast great." Both are grammatically correct, although they may have slightly different shades of meaning. And since "what" can be plural or singular, it can mean either "the thing that" or "the things that."

An interesting point besides this: despite the fact that I would use a singular "makes" in the OP's sentence, I agree that only plural "make" is appropriate in a sentence like

> Blue grass pastures, fields of clover; These are what make Mansfield
>   grow.

–["What Makes Mansfield Grow,"](https://books.google.com/books?id=a9E973EAKxYC&pg=PA8&dq=%22these%20are%20what%20make%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSmP_l_LjKAhVX2GMKHUKvBMMQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22these%20are%20what%20make%22&f=false) from *Around Mansfield* by the Mansfield Historical Society

This is because I would not be comfortable saying "Blue grass pastures, fields of clover; These are the thing that makes Mansfield grow." Semantically, these are not one thing, or even one type of thing.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. For me, I see the `what` as a shorthand for `the thing that`, so I hear `Our listeners are the thing that makes our podcast possible.` .. no question about `makes` here. But I do not know whether that argument holds water.

Comment: There are countless examples of sentences on the web that use plural "what" in the construction "make X possible". I don't find these sentences ungrammatical: "Proteins are what make life possible." "They are what make this possible." "stories are what make life possible".

Comment: @sumelic Well, if they're grammatical, then it undermines your case for strictly using "makes".

Comment: Well, they use _make_ because it agrees with the plural subject.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: but the subject of the clause is "what," which is normally singular, and none of the rules for when it is plural that have been presented so far apply in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I'm astonished to see that as I write, the only response is 4 users (one commenter and 3 upvoters) claiming **our listeners** is singular, and another comment effectively endorsing the singular usage by converting the noun phrase to ***a*** group/collection of our listeners.

I can only assume this sort of nonsense somehow arises from the AmE [tendency to treat collective nouns as singular](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular). But it's hard to see how ***listeners*** could be thought of as a "collective noun" in the same way as ***class, team, family*** etc. And I'm sure not even the most committed proponent of this grammatical principle could endorse, say, *Our users **is** seriously mistaken*.

---

TL;DR: Obviously ***listeners*** is plural, regardless of whether they're ***ours*** or not.

If anyone has doubts about the plurality of ***what***, check out [grammarphobia](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/06/subject-complement.html), where it says...

> *Note that “what” is construed as **singular when the complement is singular**, and **plural when the complement is plural**.*

---

I love "AmE/BrE usage split" questions. *These are what **make** ELU interesting*. But according to NGrams, even Americans aren't likely to say *these are what **makes** ELU interesting*...

[[[image]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsKvK.png)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=these%20are%20what%20make%2Cthese%20are%20what%20makes&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthese%20are%20what%20make%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthese%20are%20what%20makes%3B%2Cc0)

And even though it's fine to say what's between your ears ***is*** your brains, no-one says [Our brains **is** what **makes** us (human)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22our%20brains%20is%20what%20makes%20us%22). Where that link just has a couple of "accidental collocations" - the standard form is [*Our brains **are** what **make** us human*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22our%20brains%20are%20what%20make%20us%22).

Comment: @sumelic: Wow! And you're a native speaker? Amazingly, I can't find a clear-cut earlier question addressing this on either ELU or ELL ([this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114123/) is the best I could come up with). But check out [this link](https://www.englishforums.com/English/AllPluralSingular/xkgvr/post.htm). Do you still think ***what*** is inherently singular?

Comment: @sumelic: Do I really need to "show" that ***listeners*** is plural? You could just compare it to ***listener***. The fact that it's possible to create extended phrases such as *a group of listeners* is beside the point, since that's not what's been done in OP's example.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I didn't read Ghaith's comment carefully enough. (I thought it had are...is, but it actually has is...is.) I've posted an answer now where you can see my argument/thoughts.

Comment: From the [grammarphobia link](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/06/subject-complement.html): "When “what” is the subject of the clause, it agrees in number—singular or plural—with the complement.
For example, both of these sentences are correct: “She’s eating what looks like caviar” … “She’s eating what look like tiny black marbles.” Note that “what” is construed as singular when the complement is singular, and plural when the complement is plural."

I read this as an argument _for_ `makes` in the original sentence.

Comment: @sumelic: *complement* can have different meanings, but I'm not sure any of them are useful in this context. I would say [it's a pronoun](http://partofspeech.org/what-part-of-speech-is-what/) - the example given there being *What we need is commitment*, where it "stands for" the singular ***commitment***. But in OP's example ***what*** is a pronoun standing for plural ***our listeners***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: in the explanation you linked to, "complement" refers not to "what," but the other word in the clause ("caviar" or "marbles"). The word "listeners" cannot be a complement of this sort to "what" in the OP's sentence because it isn't in the clause started by "what" (the one that goes "what make/makes [podcast name] possible").

Comment: @FumbleFingers Listners is an audience. Audience is singular. The rule for singular and plural agreement based on the plurality of the subject is meaningless. One clear example is **5 weeks is a short time**. 5 weeks means one specific time span and it uses **is**. There is no reason not to use **is** after listeners.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The reason I commented with "A group/collection of our listeners" is what makes our podcast possible" was not to endorse the singular agreement. But putting "a group" or "a collection" would not cause such confusion. If you change the order of the subject and complement, the sentence will become "What makes it possible is our listeners". Then, do we need to use **are** instead of **is** in the sentence?

Comment: @Rathony: Are we still on the same planet? Sure, *5 weeks **is** a short time* because the context doesn't allow you to treat it as plural, but *Looking at the sales figures for last year, 5 weeks **stand** out as unusual* (because the context doesn't allow you to treat them as either a single item or a single span of time). I really get the feeling you and sumelic are slavishly misapplying principles relevant to usages other than the text under consideration. Do you seriously dispute the implications of my NGram above, for example, and claim you're reflecting "common usage"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am not disputing your argument nor Ngram implication. Usages are there and I just played the devil's advocate. Many rules, especially on subject-verb or complement agreement seem to be changing. The old principles may not survive very long. I absolutely agree to using **are** after listeners. But I don't agree to using **are** in "What makes it possible **is** our listeners". Let me research on this further.

Comment: @Rathony: Please do the research. I still find it hard to believe the current state of the votes here, after 48 people have visited the page. I was originally going to closevote as General Reference, but it's starting to look pretty obvious that a lot of people are at the very least *uncertain* where they stand on this usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I will do. I was shocked when I heard "Do you remember when we was young" on one American TV show. I thought about it, and said to my self, "Why the hell not?" Now, all I need is some research. This issue is complicated and I am more than eager to listen to other users' opinion.

Comment: @Michael: I'm not clear whether you're endorsing *Our listeners **are** what **makes** this possible*, or whether you're implying both verbs should be in the singular: *Our listeners **is** what **makes** this possible.* Not that I personally endorse either, but it might make a difference to some people.

Comment: @Rathony: I ***were*** brought up in a country where dialect abounds, and people often say things like that (especially, *Northerners*). But I wouldn't seriously defend the "grammaticality" of such usages. Why the hell not? Because it's ***totally ungrammatical**!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers It was only around 20 years ago when there was this grammatical rule that you could use only **were**  in the subjunctive mood regardless of the subject. It's changed over the years and people say using was in "**If I was young, I could....**" is grammatical. Nobody said it was grammatical at that time. That's for sure.

Comment: @Rathony: If I were going to make an issue of it, I could cite [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+i+was+you%2Cif+i+were+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20i%20were%20you%3B%2Cc0) showing that although dialectal and younger speakers often avoid the subjunctive *in casual speech*, it's still alive and kicking. *Long live the subjunctive*, as punny grammarians like to say! :)

Answer (score 2):

The original sentence implies question and answer. I'll start in a simple form and then move toward the OP sentence. Here is a simple form:

"What [makes] [the podcast] possible?"

```
 - "X makes [the podcast] possible," if X is singular. 
    - or "X does."
 - "X make [the podcast] possible," if X is plural. 
    - or "X do."
```

Where X is plural, English grammar requires the shift from singular (what makes) to plural (X do) between the question and answer. The question suggests but does not require a singular response, and when a plural is offered as an answer, it implies a sort of correction to the original question's suggestion.

To move a bit further toward the OP sentence: "What [is it that makes] [the podcast] possible?" And in the same way, a response may be singular or plural.

```
 - "X is."
 - "X are."
```

Now, English lets us pose and answer the question in the same sentence. In doing so, the statement retains the implicit correction of the original question. It helps to put quotation marks around the original question. Like so:

```
 - "X are 'what makes [the podcast] possible.'"
```

I think that the sentence contains a pleasing incongruity that draws in a curious listener. It contains a question, an answer, and a surprise, in a compact form. English is cool.

But the OP sentence implies the question: *"What [*make*] [the podcast] possible?" This definitely sounds weird in idiom, although grammatically I think it is acceptable. I would more typically say something like "What [things] make [the podcast] possible?" And the answer would be: "X are the things that do." This, however, is clunky, and so I would replace "the things that" with "what," like so:

```
 - What things make [the podcast] possible?
     - X are [the things that] make it possible.
     - X are [what] make it possible.
```

Using "what" as a plural relative pronoun in this instance is totally acceptable English - evidenced in part by the fact that native speakers should have no trouble understanding the OP sentence.

Coffee beans are what make this post possible.

Answer (score 0):

"Our listeners are what make/makes [podcast name] possible."

It probably depends on what is inferred:

"Our listeners are [the things or people who] make this podcast possible."

"Our listeners are [the reason that] makes this podcast possible."

I think both answers are acceptable.

Comment: Hello Richard, this question is quite old and has an accepted answer (the green tick at the top). As such, it is considered, closed, and doesn't really require any more answers.

Answer (score -1):

"Our listeners are what make X." I think, here X may be [noun](http://www.englishgrammar-a2z.com/p/noun.html) (any name of podcast channel, episode, or radio channel etc).

Comment: This doesn't address the question, which is about the agreement of singular and plural, not about 'X'.