# People is/are what makes this ___

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, collective-nouns

The sentence I want to write is something along the lines of: "I believe that the people here **are** what makes this such a great place to work".

I know people is generally plural and should be followed by "are," but for some reason it sounds off to me here. I'm curious if people in this context is more appropriately describing a singular population / entity and should be followed by "is" instead?

Comment: It sounds off because of your construction *:..the people are what...* If you omitted *are what* and changed *makes* to *make*, your sentence would sound just fine.

Comment: people is followed by are: ***I believe that the people are what makes this such a great place to work***. It's fine. Grammar-wise. Just because you put in here does not make it wrong.

Comment: "People" is plural in construction.  Except when "peoples" is plural.

Comment: Related (regarding "are what makes" vs. "are what make"): [Is this correct: “Our listeners are what make X”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300797)