# If "what" is used in place of a plural noun as a subject, is the preceding verb singular?

Tags: verbs, nouns, grammatical-number

The title may be confusing, so let me give an example:

> *They are what stops him from achieving success.*

This seems strange to me, as "They" is plural while "stops" is in the singular form. Alternatively, you could have:

> *They are what stop him from achieving success.*

So, my question boils down to: which of these two is correct?

Comment: Related previous question: [Is this correct: "Our listeners are what make X"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300797/is-this-correct-our-listeners-are-what-make-x)

Comment: 'What' in this construction = 'the thing' or 'the things'. Which will depend on what precedes 'what' ... 'they [are]', 'my fears [are]' //  'it [is]', 'my fear [is]'.

Answer (score 2):

According to [The Grammarphobia Blog](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2018/03/what-2.html) (citing G O Curme; *A Grammar of the English Language*), "what" can be either singular or plural. The form of the verb would be contingent upon what the subject is.

> - *Books **are** what make you smarter* —
>
> because the principal subject is “books.”

> In a sentence starting with a singular principal subject we’d choose a > singular verb:
>
> - *Education is what makes you smarter.*

In your case, the correct form would be "They are what *stop*..."

Comment: Yes, but if _what stop(s) him from achieving success_ is regarded not as an NP in a fused relative construction, but as a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question), then one would expect singular "stops", since the meaning is "They are the answer to the question 'What stops him from achieving success?'" Note that in general, the pronoun "what" has the default value singular.

Comment: But on balance, I'd say that it's a fused relative construction with _what stop him from achieving success_ being an NP, thus it is comparable with _They are the things that stop him from achieving success_, with plural agreement.